# Отправка данных в виде массива с form

Tags: php, html, массивы

Можно ли отправит с input массив что бы вышло так:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 122216515
    [value] => Array
        (
            [0] => 29535 
            [1] => 3224795 
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно

```
<form action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="122216515">
  <input type="hidden" name="value[]" value="29535">
  <input type="hidden" name="value[]" value="3224795">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Нельзя ли все сделать в один input? у меня input выводится через цикл сделала типа такого вроде `<input type="checkbox" name="value[<?=$itemCatsSearch->GetId()?>][]" value="<?=$itemCatsValues->GetId()?>">` но это не совсем то что надо

Comment: Через один input нельзя можно все сделать в цикле